# Word to describe something characterized by facades?

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a word like facadal or facadeous? The context it is being used in is - 
"in an increasingly ___ society".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is *facetious* (for humor) but you seem to be describing *superficial*.

> [***superficial***](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/superficial) - appearing to be true or real until examined more closely

Comment: This seems to be the right fit. +1

Answer (score 0):

Not an adjective, but *Potemkin village* fits your basic criteria.  [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Potemkin_village):

> In politics and economics a Potemkin village is any construction
>   (literal or figurative) built solely to deceive others into thinking
>   that a situation is better than it really is. The term comes from
>   stories of a fake portable village built solely to impress Empress
>   Catherine II by her former lover Grigory Potemkin during her journey
>   to Crimea in 1787.